# What is the ASBBA-001 battery connector (GoPro Fusion 360 camera)?

Tags: batteries, identification, connector

I am designing a PCB that will be powered by a battery. The battery model is the one used by the GoPro Fusion 360 camera. Specifically, it is the [ASBBA-001](https://gopro.com/en/us/shop/accessories/gopro-fusion-rechargeable-battery/ASBBA-001.html) battery. I need to know which is the model of the male connector compatible with the battery. Any ideas? Do you at least know what type of connector it is? Could it be a blade connector?

[image: photo of batteries with connector]

Comment: The proper datasheet will tell mating connectors. You need more than pictures for this. What pitch is it, to begin with? Check the camera and charger instead, to see what the mating connector looks like.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that there is no datasheet available (at least I couldn't find it). The exact model of the original battery is the 'SBDC1B' and the manufacturer 'DongGuan Amperex Technology Limited' but the manufacturer does not provide any information. As for the pitch, I am waiting to receive two batteries to be able to measure it. I think it is 2.5mm. It is only an estimate considering that the width of the battery is 11.41mm.

Comment: Then pick a different part that has a datasheet. Don't design in useless, undocumented components. Suppliers that can't even provide a datasheet are just as likely to not provide the actual components either.